# Why Is KD-Tree-based Nearest Neighbor Exponential in K?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, data-structures, search-trees, nearest-neighbour, search

I've read in many papers on higher-dimensional nearest neighbor search that KD-Trees are exponential in K, but I can't seem to determine why.

What I'm looking for is a solid runtime-complexity analysis which explains this aspect of the problem.

Comment: Quick thought is that `k` is effectively the dimension of the problem and so it suffers from the "curse of dimensionality."

Answer (score 2):

kNN tends to be exponential because the search space increases with $2^k$. Imagine you partition the space around your search point into quadrants. For k=1 you just have to search two 'quadrants' (higher and lower values), for k=2 it's 4 quadrants, for k=3 it's 8 quadrants, i.e. exponential growth of search space. That is what the kD-tree suffers from, because it has to search $2^k$ sub-branches.

Other trees perform much better, for example the [CoverTree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_tree). I also found that the PH-Tree works quite well, it seems to consistently take twice as long as the CoverTree for datasets between k=8 and k=27 (I didn't have datasets with higher k).

Comment: Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/271/) for a short introduction.